# Jquery how do i perform a class change function before the next click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of script that get some data and puts it in a `class` called `.tile-area-main`

I need to be able to know how to delay the entire `click` to introduce a new `class` that will be a animation that will run for a seconds before moving on to the new click.... how do i go about this ? ...

**(I am sure a timeout with add class is kinda what i have been researching)**

the script in question

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('data-url') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
        $('.tile-area-main').load(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have provided answer for your problem, `setTimeout` might be

Comment: i don't know how to do this it is just speculation at this stage ... care to help ?

Comment: ... I am also unsure of the syntax on where I would put in the timeout function remove classA and add class B for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

*Code*

```
$("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //remove and add the required classs
  $(yourElement).removeClass('a').addClass('b');

  //Delay the execution of load
  setTimeout(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('.tile-area-main').load(url);
  }, 1000); //Time interval in milliseconds 
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when i add specific classes that I have currently

Comment: still having problems can we go to chat on this ?

Comment: @blackdogbarking, I have only added only relevant code, sure ping me

Comment: yes what you have added makes sense to me but it still isn't working